# How do I fix this error when running a cron job for Moodle 3.9?

Tags: php, cron, ubuntu-18.04, moodle, lampp

I have a Moodle site running on localhost. Everything seems to be running fine, but I can't seem to run the cron job. I keep getting the error when I try to run `sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php` from the command line.

```
!!! <p>Error: Database connection failed</p>
<p>It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.</p>
<p>The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php</p> !!!
```

Moodle is installed on a Lampp (`/opt/lampp/htdocs/`), and this is my configuration file. My moodle data is in `/var/moodledata` I've changed the user for the database, used a password, but nothing works.

```
$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = '';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbsocket' => '',
  'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;
```

Comment: So you mean that your Moodle site is running (you can browse it, create course etc.), but cron is failing with DB connection error?

Comment: @Dolfa Yes, exactly. I can create courses, browse through it, and go to site administration and other things. But whenever I try to set up the cron job, I get that error in the terminal. But I'm running moodle on localhost. I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: Is that only error there? Isn't it complaining about permission issue? (Unable to create directory for example.) In that case I would check if you are running cron.php with same user/permission as actual webserver. Did you try to run cron.php with sudo?

Comment: @Dolfa I tried running with `sudo`. Also, I changed the folder permissions to `777`. I'm not sure what you mean as the same user/permission as the acutal webserver. Also, when I run `/usr/bin/wget http://localhost/moodle/admin/cron.php`, I get `!!! Sorry, internet access to this page has been disabled by the administrator. !!!`

Answer (score 0):

You need unmark "Site administration/General/Security/Site security settings/Cron execution via command line only" option for run cron with url.